# Redirect e Route no Laravel 5.5, é possível?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Estou com uma dificuldade de iniciante aqui no meu treinamento com Laravel 5.5
Acabei de criar um método de update - Atualizar,

```
public function atualizar(Request $request, $id)
{
    $dados = $request->all();

    if(isset($dados['situacao']))
    {
        $dados['situacao'] = "Ativa";
    }
    else
    {
        $dados['situacao'] = "Inativa";
    }

    Empresa::find($id)->update($dados);

    $mensagem = "Empresa altera com sucesso!";
    return redirect()->route('admin.empresas')->with('mensagem', $mensagem);
}
```

A atualização esta sendo realizada corretamente, mas a mensagem não esta sendo retornada para a tela para um alert.
Este `redirect` que estou utilizando não esta correto?

Valeu.

Comment: como você está fazendo na view?

Comment: Assim Virgilio: `@if (session('mensagem'))
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{$mensagem}}</div>
@endif`

Comment: faz assim: `@if (Session::has('mensagem'))  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{session('mensagem')}}</div> @endif` !!!

Comment: Não deu certo, mensagem não apareceu

Comment: faz assim agora no método `return redirect(route('admin.empresas'))->with('mensagem', $mensagem);` eu to no banco kkk

Comment: Retornei agora aqui, não deu certo também. :(

Comment: Coloque sua `View`!

Comment: Coloquei na minha dúvida, olha lá

Comment: Primeiro olha o meu comentário, e depois me fala não aparece o texto? ou não aparece nada? a Caixa aparece?

Comment: Virgilio me desculpe, o codigo errado, não era no formulario que a mensagem deveria aparecer, e sim em uma lista.

Comment: Ai seguindo sua dica de return, tive que fazer o seguinte para dar certo
`@if (Session::has('mensagem'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{Session::get('mensagem')}}</div>
                    @endif`

Comment: deu certo ?....

Comment: Simmm, valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Apos trocas de várias mensagens com @Virgilio, resolvi da seguinte maneira:

No controle coloquei o seguinte retorno:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.empresas')->with('mensagem', $mensagem);
```

Já na View, realizei a seguinte verificação:

```
@if (Session::has('mensagem'))
   <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{Session::get('mensagem')}</div>
@endif
```